# how to make border-right's height according to vertical-middle

Tags: html, css

i'm an Asian person. I'm sorry because i'm not good at English writing and grammar.

I am designing a bulletin board's view page using HTML, JSP, CSS, and I'm implementing it using  tag.

I want to implement distinguished right line between  and  tag,  a written information such as writer, viewed number, title, etc,.   like bottom image.the line looks like applied vertical-middle line of height value.
I want to implement this using CSS Attribute related border-right.

How can I design this using CSS ? pls T.T;;

please refer to the bottom exam's image that i want to make. 
[image]
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by applying css 
 border property like - 
    border-right: thick groove black;
  Or
You can apply sign convention like | between content.
 I hope my answer may help you.
  if it does, please upgrade me.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this is what you need

```css
.overview { border-top: medium solid darkgray; }
.row {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
  border-bottom: thin solid darkgray;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 6em;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.h6 {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}

.b-r {
  border-right: thin solid darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="overview">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="h6 b-r">title</span>
    <span>today's calendar</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="h6 b-r">writer</span>
    <span class="b-r">administrator</span>
    <span class="h6 b-r">date</span>
    <span class="b-r">2017-06-15</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="h6 b-r">appended file</span>
    <span>TimeTable.pdf</span>
  </div>
</div>
```